# Invalid expression term error in the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

- Error    1 The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments
- Error    2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

  It gives me error in  "int.TryParse(surveys.First(), out id);"

  ```
     L
        var surveys = (from su in DbContext.Surveys
                                 where su.userName == su.userName 
                                 select su.ID);
  if(surveys.Count() > 0)
              {
               int id = 0;
               int.TryParse(surveys.First(), out id);
                 return id;
               }
               return 0;
  ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove int from TryParse();

```
int.TryParse(surveys.First(), out int id);
```

should be

```
int.TryParse(surveys.First(), out id);
```

Change :-

```
List<SurveyContext> surveys = (from su in DbContext.Surveys
                                          where su.userName == su.userName 
                                          select su.ID).ToList();
```

to

```
List<string> surveys = (from su in DbContext.Surveys
                                          where su.userName == su.userName 
                                          select su.ID);
```

You are trying to select `string` type in Linq and putting it in `List<SomeType>` which should be `List<int>`.

```
  var surveys = (from su in DbContext.Surveys
                                              where su.userName == su.userName 
                                              select su.ID);

  //Code follows
  int.TryParse(surveys.First(), out id);
```

Comment: +1:  I was editing the question so you beat me to the answer :)

Comment: I had without int and gave me a lot of mistakes... :(

Comment: yes... Errors: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string, out int)' has some invalid arguments 
Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MvcAnketaIT.Models.SurveyContext' to 'string'

Comment: What is MvcAnketaIT.Models.SurveyContext? you need to pass in the string representation to TryParse, not a complex type

Comment: @radiolaDollani See this [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

Comment: @radiolaDollani it should be List<string>. Just use `var` it will give you what you want.

Comment: with <string> it gives me one error... with var 3 errors... see updates

Comment: Remove tolist from the query

Comment: it gives me error to "select": Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this. Move the int datatype to the declaration of the variable, and add a property field name after the First() method. (or whatever equivalent property you have on the Survey object that holds its Id)

```
if(surveys.Count() > 0)
{
    int id = 0;
    int.TryParse(surveys.First().Id, out id);
    return id;
}
return null;
```

**UPDATE**:
I see you've updated the question, it looks like what you have should do the trick..